# Sinch will work with Codename one API

Tags: android, ios, codenameone, sinch

As Sinch API provides Video calling capabilities, I would like to know Sinch API will work with IOS, Android Apps developed using Codename One API. If yes, please refer any documentation.

Comment: a little google before asking can really help you (and us). Looking for `Sinch API` on google has doc as the first result

Comment: maybe if codename one supports to bridge in native libraries for each platform

Answer (score 0):

Codename One supports native interfaces so you can integrate support for pretty much everything. This is explained in https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html[this video] and in the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/advanced-topics.html).

There are some open source native libraries you can use as reference. [Mina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6075854/mina) seems to be working on porting OpenTok to Codename One which might be interesting to you.